# I can access 127.0.0.1, but not http://localhost:8080

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem. I am trying to run a simple JSP page from Eclipse:
http://postimg.org/image/z268cl1s3/

But when I run this page i get a 404 error:
http://postimg.org/image/h0rosix4z/

When I put in:
localhost
127.0.0.1

in the browser it works fine:
http://postimg.org/image/8js6hlsg3/

I can see eclipse is running it from localhost:8080, but when i type that in at the browser it gives me this error:
http://postimg.org/image/7lbtfbf43/

Does anyone know how I can activate localhost on my mac. I looked up several tutorials, but i didnt find the answer. MySQL is also running fine on the computer, so I guess there is something that dont let me access [http://localhost:8080?]

Hope someone can help me?
Best Regards
Mads

Comment: Did you tried to start TomCat on another port? Maybe 8080 is not free

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues you are having:

1. There is a difference between `http://localhost/` (and its equivalent `http://127.0.0.1`) and `http://localhost:8080` - the first uses port 80, the second 8080. The Tomcat server listens only to the latter, that is shown by the servers error messages, and not generic 404 messages. In other words, do not forget to add the 8080 port numbers to the end of the `localhost` url
2. The Tomcat error messages show that the resources are not available, so I would look at what Java web applications are installed - e.g. the root web application is missing (the `localhost:8080` url) for sure, and I am not sure whether your MySQL connector is.

Answer (score 0):

Search google for how adding an entry to the hosts file on your mac.

You'll basically link localhost to 127.0.0.1 there

Comment: The default host file does this, it shouldn't be necessary to do it manually.

Comment: Actually, the default host file does not do this. The particular line must be uncommented to take effect.